# How to round up number inside HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an Input field to which if I enter a decimal value I want to round it off to its next highest number, but the problem is that whenever I type a dot (".") the onChnage gets triggered, rounds it off and then updates the value, so basically I'm not able to type anything after the dot ("."). I can't use onBlur here, can someone tell me what I can do

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { TextInputHelperCurrency } from '@honeycomb-npm/honeycomb-react';

export type LoanAmountProps = {
    label: string;
    errorMessage: string;
    defaultLoanAmount: string;
    minLoanAmount: string;
    maxLoanAmount: string;
};

const LoanAmount: React.VFC = () => {
    const [enteredLoanAmount, setEnteredLoanAmount] = useState<string>('10000');
    const handleAmountChange = (value: string) => {
        const roundedUpValue = Math.ceil(Number(value));
        setEnteredLoanAmount(String(roundedUpValue));
    };

    return (
        <div className="loan-amount">
            <TextInputHelperCurrency
                data-testid="textInputHelperCurrency"
                id="loanAmount"
                value={enteredLoanAmount}
                onChange={handleAmountChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoanAmount;
```

Comment: If you cannot use `onBlur` event, you need to create an event listener where you check if user has clicked outside your input field. If it is so, round off the value. Otherwise let him keep typing the value.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on **ReactTS**, but I will answer the solution in **ReactJS**. Feel free to edit the solution or suggest changes for TS.

Firstly, create a `useRef` hook which will be passed in the `TextInputHelperCurrency` as `innerRef` prop. Next, in `useEffect` hook, check if the `useRef` hook created above has loaded and if there is a click, and `useRef` hook does not contains the target event Node, then round up the value.

In the `TextInputHelperCurrency` component, accept `innerRef` as prop and attach the `innerRef` as `ref` to the parent tag of `return` statement. Here is the code:

```
const LoanAmount: React.VFC = () => {
  const [enteredLoanAmount, setEnteredLoanAmount] = useState<string>('10000');
  const textInputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClickEvent = (event) => {
      if (
        textInputRef.current &&
        !textInputRef.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        const roundedUpValue = Math.ceil(Number(textInputRef.current.value));
        setEnteredLoanAmount(String(roundedUpValue));
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClickEvent);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClickEvent);
  }, [textInputRef]);

  return (
    <div className='loan-amount'>
      <TextInputHelperCurrency
        data-testid='textInputHelperCurrency'
        id='loanAmount'
        value={enteredLoanAmount}
        innerRef={textInputRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Inside `TextInputHelperCurrency` component,

```
const TextInputHelperCurrency = ({innerRef}) => {
  // some code
  return (
    <div ref={innerRef}>
      {/* some more code */}
    </div>
  )
};
```